# How to prevent a DialogFragment from dismissing on touch outside?

Tags: android, xamarin, modal-dialog, android-dialogfragment

I am using a DialogFragment which will show a fully customized view, no native button used.
I set the dialog cancealable with dialog.SetCanceledOnTouchOutside(true);
And when the user touches outside, I want to run some code to determine if the dialog should be dismissed or not.
My problem is, when an event is fired (Canceled, Dismissed), the dialog is already dismissed even before the super.Dismiss(); so I can never bypass the dismiss.

I tried many things, override the OnDismiss and OnCancel of the fragment (fired but to late), set the listeners on the dialogBuilder AND/OR on the dialog itself (not fired or too late), override the OnShow to reset the listeners etc ...

Getting stuck with this, Any idea ?

PS: Using Xamarin

```
public override Dialog OnCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    AlertDialog.Builder alertDialogBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this.Activity);
    alertDialogBuilder.SetView(myView);
    AlertDialog dialog = alertDialogBuilder.Create();
    dialog.SetCanceledOnTouchOutside(true);
    return dialog;
}

public override void OnDismiss(IDialogInterface dialog)
{
    //BreakPoint here, already dismissed
    base.OnDismiss(dialog);
}
```

Comment: you have called dialog.SetCanceledOnTouchOutside(true); **and** you want to prevent a DialogFragment from dismissing on touch outside...Seriously what you need to achieve?

Comment: I want to allow cancel onTouchOutside, but be able to interrupt it

Comment: In `onCreateDialog` itself setup `dialog.setOnDismissListener` and try

Comment: Already tried, OnDismissListener is not even fired with alertDialogBuilder.SetOnDismissListener(new OnDialogDismissListener()) nor dialog.SetOnDismissListener(new OnDialogDismissListener())

Comment: Actually the only way to make OnDialogDismissListener raise is to dialog.SetOnShowListener and in the OnShow event set alertDialog.SetOnDismissListener(new OnDialogDismissListener());
But even there it raises too late ...

Comment: just close the fragment only through a cancel button. do your stuff on cancel button click

Comment: Thank you but thats not what I want

Comment: You can try to set `dialog.SetCanceledOnTouchOutside(false);` to false, you can prevent the DialogFragment from dismissing on touch outside.

Comment: Yes, but I want to allow cancel ontouchoutside

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you want to achieve this result? If you click the outside the Dialog, we can detect the click event before the Dialog closed.
[image]

You can create a `MyAlertDialog` inherit the `AlertDialog`

```
    public class MyAlertDialog:AlertDialog
{
    public MyAlertDialog(Context c):base(c) {

    }

    protected override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);
        //Please add following code for watching outside touch
        this.Window.SetFlags(WindowManagerFlags.NotTouchModal, WindowManagerFlags.NotTouchModal);
        this.Window.AddFlags(WindowManagerFlags.WatchOutsideTouch);
    }



    public override bool OnTouchEvent(MotionEvent e)
    {
        //just used for testing.
        var sss = "test";
        //If you want to close the Dialog when click the outside the Dialog part.
        //this.Dismiss();
        return true;
    }

}
```

Following part is `DialogFragment`.

```
    public class MyDialog:Android.Support.V4.App.DialogFragment
{

    public override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);

    }


    public override Dialog OnCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {


        MyAlertDialog alertDialogBuilder = new MyAlertDialog(this.Activity);
        alertDialogBuilder.SetTitle("MyDialog");
        alertDialogBuilder.SetCanceledOnTouchOutside(true);
        return alertDialogBuilder;
    }



    public override void OnPause()
    {
        base.OnPause();
    }

    public override void OnCancel(IDialogInterface dialog)
    {
        base.OnCancel(dialog);
    }

    public override void OnDismiss(IDialogInterface dialog)
    {
        base.OnDismiss(dialog);
    }
}
```

Click the button to push the Dialog.

```
private void BtnClick_Click(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
    {
        MyDialog dialog = new MyDialog();
        dialog.Show(SupportFragmentManager, "dialog");
    }
```

Comment: That's exactly my goal.I will try this as soon as I can, thank you !

Comment: It works like a charm, I was almost there but missed the flags :(. Thank you @LeonLuMsft

Answer (score 3):

Correct solution so simple:

```
dialog?.setCanceledOnTouchOutside(false)
```

From documentation:

```
/**
 * Sets whether this dialog is canceled when touched outside the window's
 * bounds. If setting to true, the dialog is set to be cancelable if not
 * already set.
 * 
 * @param cancel Whether the dialog should be canceled when touched outside
 *            the window.
 */
```

Answer (score 3):

By now you should be using DialogFragment instead of AlertDialog so the answer is as follows:

```
isCancelable = false
```

Put that in any part of your code and you're set `setCancelable(false)` for Java

Comment: but how can you disable buttons in background ?

Answer (score 2):

This should be called on the `onCreateView()`

```
DialogFragment.getDialog().setCanceledOnTouchOutside(true);
```

Answer (score 1):

Solution that i found is:

> just close the fragment only through a cancel button. do your stuff on
>   cancel button click

```
dialog.Cancelable = false;

_cancelButton =dialog.FindViewById(Resource.Id.btnOptionOne );

_cancelButton.Click += CancelButtonPositiveButtonClick;

private void CancelButtonPositiveButtonClick (object sender, EventArgs e) {
    //do something here and dismiss the dialog if you want to:
    if (satisfied) {
        DismissDialog();
    }
}
private void DismissDialog () {
    _cancelButton.Click -= CancelButtonPositiveButtonClick;
    dialog.Dismiss ();
}
```

Comment: I want to be able to cancel, but I want to be able to interrupt canceling from code

Comment: just close the fragment only through a cancel button. do your stuff on cancel button click

Comment: I dont want a cancel button